# Serving static folder not from nginx but from uwsgi

Tags: django, nginx, static

I am using nginx - uwsgi setting.

I want to serve the static folder from uwsgi not nginx.

So I didn't set any static settings on nginx

nginx setting

```
server {
    listen      80;
    server_name dockerhost;
    charset     utf-8;
    location / {
        proxy_pass  http://127.0.0.1:8011/;
        include     /etc/nginx/uwsgi_params;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_pass_header X-XSRF-TOKEN;
    }
}
```

uwsgi start command

```
uwsgi --http :8011  --processes 4 --threads 1 --module myapp.wsgi --logto /tmp/mylog.log
```

and my django settings is here below.

settins.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = "/usr/src/app/static"

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'frontend/dist'),
)
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns += [
    path('sp/', SeparateView.as_view())
]
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += [
        re_path(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', views.serve),
    ]
```

When `DEBUG=True`, it works, static files are served,but `DEBUG=False`

{% static %} in template doesn't work for it, the file under static directories are 404 error.

I have done `manage.py collectstatic` and confirmed that there are files under `/usr/src/app/static`

Where should I check ?

Comment: what's your uwsgi configuration? here's an [example](https://lincolnloop.com/blog/serving-static-files-uwsgi/) setup

Comment: Thank you I use `--static-map /static=/usr/src/app/static` it works.